# SQL Select only rows where multiple relationships exist

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Given a parent table 'parent'

```
╔═══════════╦══════════╗
║ PARENT_ID ║   NAME   ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╣
║         1 ║ bob      ║
║         2 ║ carol    ║
║         3 ║ stew     ║
╚═══════════╩══════════╝
```

and a many-many relationship table 'rel' between parent and a (here unspecified) property  table

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════╗
║ PARENT_ID ║  PROP_ID  ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════╣
║         1 ║         5 ║
║         1 ║         1 ║
║         2 ║         5 ║
║         2 ║         4 ║
║         2 ║         1 ║
║         3 ║         1 ║
║         3 ║         3 ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

How can I select all parents that have *all* of a specified set of relationships? E.g. with the sample data, how can I find all parents that have both property 5 and 1?

---

edit:
Same question but with requirement for an *exact* match:
[SQL Select only rows where exact multiple relationships exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113267/sql-select-only-rows-where-exact-multiple-relationships-exist)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is called **[Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)**

```
SELECT  a.name
FROM    parent a
        INNER JOIN rel b
            ON a.parent_ID = b.parent_ID
WHERE   b.prop_id IN (1,5)
GROUP BY a.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c357/1)

**UPDATE 1**

if *unique constraint* was not enforce on `prop_id` for every `parent_id`, `DISTINCT` is needed on this case.

```
SELECT  a.name
FROM    parent a
        INNER JOIN rel b
            ON a.parent_ID = b.parent_ID
WHERE   b.prop_id IN (1,5)
GROUP BY a.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT b.prop_id) = 2
```

Comment: This assumes that the combination of parent_id and prop_id are always unique. You could modify the `HAVING` clause to return more precisely: `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT b.prop_id) = 2`

Comment: @Nicarus yes, as what the example records have shown. but if they are not unique assuming there is another field on the table which make the columns unique, then a `DISTINCT` keyword is required.

Comment: I'm curious - why the necessity for the 'count' clause?

Comment: the number of records returned on the query is equal to the number of values on the condition, try executing this, `SELECT  a.name
FROM    parent a
        INNER JOIN rel b
            ON a.parent_ID = b.parent_ID
WHERE   b.prop_id IN (1,5)` and see the difference.

Comment: I'm realizing that I missed a piece here.  Posted the additional requirement under: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113267/sql-select-only-rows-where-exact-multiple-relationships-exist

Answer (score 1):

name your first table a, and second table b

```
SELECT parent_id FROM prop b1 
WHERE prop_id=1 and 
EXISTS (SELECT parent_id FROM prop b2 
        WHERE b2.parent_id=b1.parent_id AND b2.prop_id=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just saw this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11648013/213042) to a different question that seems to fit this case:

```
 SELECT distinct parent_id
 FROM rel as T1
 INNER JOIN rel as T2
 ON T1.parent_id = T2.parent_id
 WHERE T1.prop_id = '1' and T2.prop_id = '5'
```

Comment: what if you need to find another `prop_id`? you need another join again? waste of resources.

Comment: It might be waste of computing resources, however the answer is totally valid and might save a lot of thinking resources for the programmer so it's worth the consideration. Don't optimize prematurely!

Answer (score 1):

I've written your table in to a CTE, let me know if you require assistance in adapting the code for your purposes.

```
;WITH MyTable AS
(
    SELECT   parent_id = 1
            ,prop_id = 5    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,1              UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,5              UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,4              UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,1              UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,1              UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,3              
)
,Eval AS
(
    SELECT   parent_id
            ,PropEval   = SUM(CASE WHEN prop_id IN (1,5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY parent_id
)
SELECT parent_id
FROM Eval
WHERE PropEval = 2
```

Comment: mysql doesn't support cte, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I didn't realise this was MySQL only. My bad.