# SQL Select only rows where exact multiple relationships exist

Tags: mysql, sql

This is closely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098243/sql-select-only-rows-where-multiple-relationships-exist), but adds another requirement.

Given a parent table 'parent'

```
╔════════════╦════════╗
║ PARENT_ID  ║ NAME   ║
╠════════════╬════════╣
║         1  ║ bob    ║
║         2  ║ carol  ║
║         3  ║ stew   ║
╚════════════╩════════╝
```

and a many-many relationship table 'rel' between parent and a (here unspecified) property  table

```
╔════════════╦══════════╗
║ PARENT_ID  ║ PROP_ID  ║
╠════════════╬══════════╣
║         1  ║       5  ║
║         1  ║       1  ║
║         2  ║       5  ║
║         2  ║       4  ║
║         2  ║       1  ║
║         3  ║       1  ║
║         3  ║       3  ║
╚════════════╩══════════╝
```

How can I select all parents that have *all of* and *only* a specified set of relationships? E.g. with the sample data, how can I find all parents that have relationships with exactly property 5 and 1?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT PARENT_ID
FROM rel
GROUP BY PARENT_ID
HAVING SUM(PROP_ID NOT IN (5,1)) = 0
   AND SUM(PROP_ID = 1) = 1 
   AND SUM(PROP_ID = 5) = 1
```

Comment: +1 but this isn't *exactly* right. It still works if one is missing.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I fixed that.

Comment: Yes. I think that is what the OP wants. Otherwise I can be changed to `HAVING SUM(PROP_ID NOT IN (5,1)) = 0 AND SUM(PROP_ID = 1)=1 and SUM(PROP_ID = 5)=1`

Comment: To quote the OP: "how can I find all parents that have relationships with **exactly** property 5 and 1"

Comment: Unfortunately mySQL does not know the minus operator. You could then just remove the set coming from the not in operator from the set computed by the in operator.

Comment: The first one is still not correct. It is possible to not have any `1`s and still fulfill the first condition, as long as you have two `5`s instead.

Comment: @Asad: ok, ok. You win. :)

Comment: @sorencito: No idea what you are talking about with `minus`operator.

Comment: @juergend you could probably just use `HAVING Count(*)=SUM(PROP_ID IN (5,1))=2`

Comment: @fthiella That doesn't quite work, because then two 5s and no 1s would still pass.

Comment: @Asad unless there are multiple rows with same property and in which case you have to use DISTINCT, i believe it's should give the same result

Comment: @juergend: Sry. Accepted. I just posted my own answer to illustrate the idea.

Answer (score 4):

This alternative has the benefit of a constant statement structure and only one parameter, independent of the amount of relations you are looking for:

```
SELECT parent_id FROM rel 
GROUP BY parent_id 
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(prop_id ORDER BY prop_id ASC SEPARATOR ",") = '1,5';
```

Disadvantages:

- You need to prepare an ordered, comma separated String of prop_ids upfront.
- This works on MySQL, but not all database servers.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to select all parents with *at least* a 5 and a 1, you can use:

```
SELECT PARENT_ID
FROM rel
GROUP BY PARENT_ID
HAVING SUM(PROP_ID = 1)
       AND SUM(PROP_ID = 5)
       AND SUM(PROP_ID NOT IN (5,1)) = 0
```

If you need *exactly* one 5 and one 1, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14113307/1726343) answer

Comment: @juergend Yeah, but I just realised it is slightly wrong. It enforces at least one of each, but not exactly 1 of each.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT PARENT_ID
FROM rel
GROUP BY PARENT_ID
HAVING
  COUNT(PROP_ID)=2 AND
  COUNT(DISTINCT case when PROP_ID IN ( 1, 5 ) then PROP_ID end)=2
```

This will select all `PARENT_ID` that have exactly two rows, with exactly two, non duplicated, `PROP_ID` that match.

Answer (score 2):

With two nested subqueries, like this..

```
 Select pa.Id
 From parents pa
 Where not exists -- This ensures that all specifies properties exist
    (Select * From property y
     Where propertyId In (1,5)
         And Not Exists
             (Select * From parentProperty
              Where parentId = pa.parentId 
                  And propertyId = y.propertyId ))
   And not exists -- This ensures that only specified list of properties exist
    (Select * From parentProperty
     Where parentId = pa.parentId 
        And propertyId Not In (1,5) )
```

The first one reads 
"Show me all the parents where there is ***not*** a property in the specified list of properties that is not in the parent properties table for the specified parent...."

The second subquery reads:
"also make sure that there does not exist a record in the parentProperties table for that parent for any property that is ***not*** in the specified list."

Answer (score 1):

Assuming (PARENT_ID, PROP_ID) is unique:

```
SELECT r1.PARENT_ID
FROM rel r1
INNER JOIN rel r2 ON r1.PARENT_ID = r2.PARENT_ID AND r2.PROP_ID = 5 
INNER JOIN rel r3 ON r1.PARENT_ID = r3.PARENT_ID AND r3.PROP_ID = 1
GROUP BY r1.PARENT_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Or,

```
SELECT parent.PARENT_ID
FROM parent
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT PARENT_ID
    FROM rel
    WHERE PROP_ID IN (1,5)
    GROUP BY PARENT_ID
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
) good ON parent.PARENT_ID = good.PARENT_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN rel bad ON parent.PARENT_ID = bad.PARENT_ID 
    AND bad.PROP_ID NOT IN (1,5)
WHERE bad.PARENT_ID IS NULL
```

Or even,

```
SELECT DISTINCT parent.PARENT_ID
FROM parent
INNER JOIN rel r2 ON parent.PARENT_ID = r2.PARENT_ID AND r2.PROP_ID = 5 
INNER JOIN rel r3 ON parent.PARENT_ID = r3.PARENT_ID AND r3.PROP_ID = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN rel r0 ON parent.PARENT_ID = r0.PARENT_ID 
    AND r0.PROP_ID NOT IN (1,5)
WHERE r0.PARENT_ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If MySql supported `minus`, the query could look like this:

```
select parent_id
from rel
where prop_id in (5,1)
group by parent_id
having count(distinct prop_id)=2 and count(prop_id)=2
minus
select parent_id
from rel
where prop_id not in (5,1);
```

The `not in` will remove those relationships that exceed (5,1), e.g. (5,1,3).

I know you're using MySql and my answer hence is wrong. Just take it as another idea.

Comment: MySql doesn't support minus, but even if it would, your query will return also parent_id where just one of the attributes matches, and also parent_id where duplicated attributes exists. pls see this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ed577/6/0 second query should be correct

Comment: @fthiella Thanks for your input - I corrected the query according to your fiddle. I didn't expect the table to contain duplicates and did not notice the mistake in the first IN clause.

Answer (score 0):

This query is true even if (PARENT_ID, PROP_ID) is not unique:

```
SELECT PARENT_ID FROM rel WHERE
PROP_ID IN (5,1) AND 
PARENT_ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT PARENT_ID FROM rel WHERE PROP_ID NOT IN (5,1))
GROUP BY PARENT_ID HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PROP_ID) = 2
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help you:

```
SELECT p.PARENT_ID , r.PROP_ID FROM rel r LEFT JOIN parent p ON p.PARENT_ID = r.PARENT_ID WHERE r.PROP_ID = 5 OR r.PROP_ID = 1
```

Comment: The output is wrong, as it contains duplicates and also those parent_ids with other relationships than (5,1).

Answer (score -3):

You can do this with a group by.

SELECT PARENT_ID
FROM link_tbl
WHERE PROP_ID IN (5,1)
GROUP BY PARENT_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2

Comment: The count in the `HAVING` is applied after the `WHERE` filter though, so they may have others.