# SQL query over parents with exact same set of children

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, relational-division

I have parent-child relation in my table (simplified version listed below):

```
| parent | child |
|--------+-------|
| p1     | c1    |
| p1     | c2    |
|--------+-------|
| p2     | c1    |
| p2     | c2    |
|--------+-------|
| p3     | c1    |
|--------+-------|
| p4     | c2    |
|--------+-------|
| p5     | c3    |
```

I need to query all parents with the exact same set of children like `p1` and `p2`.

Seems to be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113267/sql-select-only-rows-where-exact-multiple-relationships-exist), but there are *hard-coded* children.

Comment: Sounds like you'll need a recursive CTE to build up a structure which aggregates children - and then you can group by the children.

Comment: what is the possible output you expecting

Comment: @A5l-lE5 single-column table of `parent` I suppose

Comment: For the whole table or for a given parent?

Comment: that means you wanted to fetch all the parents having same set of childs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query lists all parents sharing the same children, where there are more than one parent:

```
SELECT array_agg(parent) AS parents, children, count(*) AS dupes
FROM (
   SELECT parent, array_agg(child ORDER BY child) AS children
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 2
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Simple, but not the fastest possible solution. For *big* tables, I would try something else.

The problem belongs to the "relational division" family. Here is a collection of query styles we assembled some time ago:
[How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879#7774879)

One way (of many) to get **single parent per row**:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT parent, array_agg(child ORDER BY child) AS children
   FROM   tbl
   GROUP  BY 1
   )
SELECT *
FROM   cte c
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   cte c1
   WHERE  c1.children = c.children
   AND    c1.parent <> c.parent
   );
```

Comment: Great! But how can I eliminate multiple results per cell like     `{p1,p2}`?

Comment: @ilardm: I think I answered the given question as good as possible. There is nothing about eliminating anything in the question. I suggest you ask a *new question* with your new (precise) requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll accept it as soon as `parents` column could be usable for further queries (please refer [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22525073/sql-query-over-parents-with-exact-same-set-of-children#comment34277620_22525073))

Comment: @ilardm: Added a single parent version. Essential information should be in the question, not scattered in comments. Use `edit` to improve (not change) your question.