# yii2 andFilterWhere to return only query where all params are matched

Tags: yii2

This is closely related to [SQL Select only rows where exact multiple relationships exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113267/sql-select-only-rows-where-exact-multiple-relationships-exist) but I'm looking for a Yii2 solution to this.

```
╔════════════╦════════╗
║ PARENT_ID  ║ NAME   ║
╠════════════╬════════╣
║         1  ║ bob    ║
║         2  ║ carol  ║
║         3  ║ stew   ║
╚════════════╩════════╝

╔════════════╦══════════╗
║ PARENT_ID  ║ PROP_ID  ║
╠════════════╬══════════╣
║         1  ║       5  ║
║         1  ║       1  ║
║         2  ║       5  ║
║         2  ║       4  ║
║         2  ║       1  ║
║         3  ║       1  ║
║         3  ║       3  ║
╚════════════╩══════════╝
```

I need to select only parents that have all of the relationships specified.

Using `andFilterWhere` returns a query if **any** of the relationships are matched:

```
$this->prop_arr = Array(1,5);
$query->andFilterWhere( ['in', 'prop.prop_id', $this->prop_arr ] );
```

This returns rows that have prop_id=1 or prop_id=5, I need rows to be returned only if they have prop_id=1 **AND** prop_id=5

So it should only return parent_id 1 & 2, but returns all three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an `andFilterWhere` solution but maybe it will help.

```
$props = [5, 1];
$having = ['and', new \yii\db\Expression('SUM(PROP_ID NOT IN (' . implode(',', $props) . ')) = 0')];
foreach ($props as $prop) {
    $having[] = ['and', new \yii\db\Expression("SUM(PROP_ID = $prop) = 1")];
}
ParentProp::find()
    ->select('PARENT_ID')
    ->groupBy('PARENT_ID')
    ->having($having)
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

You need to make sure `$props` array contains only trusted values.

Comment: Yeah it all gets validated, I just pulled out the values to simplify the question... Why `asArray()`? I assume that's not necessary

Comment: Yes, it's just to get array instead of object, use whatever you prefer.

Comment: So I think this is missing some `AND` because syntax error comes up, I added `AND SUM(PROP...` but the array seems to be passed out of order and the result is `HAVING AND SUM(prop_id = 1) = 1 SUM(PROP_ID NOT IN (1,3)) = 0 AND SUM(PROP_ID = 3) = 1)` which doesn't work

Comment: there should not be `and` between `having`  and `sum` but the order of `sum` parts is not important.

Comment: Right, but thats how it comes out when I added `$having[] = new \yii\db\Expression("AND SUM(PROP_ID = $prop) = 1")` the first expression comes in second...

Comment: This is strange, I have no idea.

Comment: I moved it into two arrays but now I'm getting `Operator 'SUM(PROP_ID NOT IN (1,2,3)) = 0' requires two operands.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use andWhere instead of andFilterWhere :

```
  $this->prop_arr = Array(1,5);
  $query->andWhere( ['in', 'prop.prop_id', $this->prop_arr ] );
```