# Reverse query on a has_many :through

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Scenario:

```
Team
has_many :players, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, through: :players

Player
belongs_to :team
belongs_to :user

User
```

So, let's say that i have 4 teams with different users:

```
Team 1
User 1, User 2

Team 2
User 2, User 3

Team 3
User 1

Team 4
User 2, User 4, User 5
```

Now, suppose i have the id of two users, (`User 1`, `User 5`), and i want to know if there is any team which consists of **ONLY** these two players. Let's say i have a team that consists of users 1, 2 and 5. The query should not bring this team.

How can i use `ActiveRecord` semantics in my favor to do this? It is easy to get all players from a team, but i couldn't find a way to do the opposite.

Comment: Do they have to be in the same team, maybe with others users, or do they have to be the only players of that team?

Comment: @MrYoshiji The only players in that team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** AH! I got it in pure SQL:

```
users = User.first(2)
Team.joins(:users).group('teams.id').having('SUM( CASE WHEN users.id in (?) THEN 1 ELSE -1 END ) = ?', users, users.count)
```

Try it and let me know if it works for you (working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bb2a9/8 and the same example but with 3 players: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bb2a9/10)

---

This is not optimized on the DB level as it uses a lot of ruby/rails code, but can you try it?

```
users = User.first(2)
# find teams with that exact number of players associated
teams = Team.joins(:users).group('teams.id').having('COUNT(users.id) = ?', users.count)
# find players referencing to those teams with other users than the ones specified
players_to_ignore = Player.where(team_id: teams).where('user_id NOT IN (?)', users)
# get Teams where associated players id is not in the previous list
Team.where(id: teams).joins(:players).where('players.id NOT IN (?)', players_to_ignore)
```

Comment: I'll try and give u a feedback

Answer (score 1):

You can use two where clauses:

One for getting all the `Teams` having exactly two users.

```
Team.joins(:users).group("teams.id").having("count('distinct users.id') = 2").select("teams.id")
```

Second for having all `Teams` with users `1` and `5`.

```
Team.joins(:users).where('users.id in (?)', [1,5]).group("teams.id").having("count('distinct users.id') = 2").select("teams.id")
```

Intersection of these two should give you what you need.
So to combine it all:

```
Team.where(id: Team.joins(:users).group("teams.id").having("count('distinct users.id') = 2").select("teams.id")).where(id: Team.joins(:users).where('users.id in (?)', [1,5]).group("teams.id").having("count('distinct users.id') = 2").select("teams.id"))
```

Comment: Context: we are looking for Teams composed of User 1 and 2. Team #3 has User 1 and User 3. This Team #3 will be found by your first instruction (has 2 players), and then found again because one of its players has an id in [1,2].

Answer (score 0):

```
Team.join(:users).where('users.id in (?)', [1,5]).
select { |team| team.users.map(&:id).sort == [1,5] }
```

#### Previous answer (For pre edited question)

Will this works for you?

```
Team.join(:users).where('users.id in (?)', [1,5])
```

You can do the same on user model by

```
# user.rb
has_many :teams, through: :works
has_many :works, foreign_key: :user_id
```

#### Responding to your edits & comment

Hacky:

```
Team.join(:users).where('users.id in (?)', [1,5]).
select { |team| team.users.map(&:id).sort == [1,5] }
```

Better?

> [SQL Select only rows where exact multiple relationships exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113267/sql-select-only-rows-where-exact-multiple-relationships-exist)

Comment: This won't work, because i need the team that have only these two players. Suppose i have a team with users 1, 2 and 5. This query would bring this team too.

Comment: @MurifoX Updated the answers