# SQL Join only if all records have a match

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables:

- CP_carthead (idOrder)
- CP_cartrows (idOrder, idCartRow)
- CP_shipping (idCartRow, idShipping, dateShipped)

There can be multiple idCartRows per idOrder.

I want to get all orders where **all** its idCartRows exist in CP_shipping. This seems like it should be simple, but I haven't found much on the web.

Here's my query now:

```
SELECT
    s.idOrder
    , s.LatestDateShipped
FROM
    CP_carthead o
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                        SELECT
                            MAX(s.dateShipped) [LatestDateShipped]
                            , r.idOrder
                        FROM
                            CP_shipping s
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN CP_cartrows r ON s.idCartRow = r.idCartRow
                        GROUP BY
                            r.idOrder               
                    ) s ON o.idOrder = s.idOrder
```

Comment: From looking at the query why not just use the sub query and drop the outer? And change the `left join` to `CP_cartrows` to an `inner join`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Select only rows where multiple relationships exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098243/sql-select-only-rows-where-multiple-relationships-exist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is returning rows from "s" and not the orders.  Based on your question, I came up with this query:

```
select o.*
from CP_Carthead o
where o.orderId in (select cr.idOrder
                    from cp_cartrows cr left outer join
                         cp_shipping s
                         on cr.idCartRow = s.IdCartrow  
                    group by cr.idOrder
                    having count(s.idCartRow) = COUNT(*)
                   )
```

The subquery in the `in` statement is getting orders all of whose cartrows are in shipping.

Comment: He is selecting values only from the joined sub-query, yours only from  `CP_Carthead`

Comment: @Magnus . . . I know.  I am answering the question ("I want to get orders . . . "), not replicating the query.

Comment: This worked for me. My query now looks the same as was - I just added the where clause. Is there a better way to implement this method?

Comment: @Rivka . . . An `in` with a subquery can be replaced by a `join`.  However, the `in` is often the clearer way to express the query.